# Using simple quotes "" instead of \text{}

Tags: macros, xetex

Is there a way to use `newcommand` or some other nice technique to transform any occurence of

```
"bla"
```

in *math mode* into

```
\text{bla}
```

The reason I ask is because it is easy, and doesn't interrupt the flow of reading the (La)TeX code as much.

I would like to keep Xe(La)TeX's nice quote behavior (ie it can use the regular "" instead of backticks to quote some text outside math mode).

Comment: It might be more desirable to use some auto-complete / auto-expansion in your editor of choice, as opposed to the (albeit interesting) solution of @Martin

Comment: @Pieter: I'm trying to remove the obstructive `\text{}` commands to improve general readability of the tex code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think that marking code this way adds to its readability. Nevertheless, you can change the behavior of `"` in math mode with the following TeX magic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1"{\text{#1}}
\mathcode`"="8000

\begin{document}
"Abc" $f_"abc"$
\end{document}
```

However, keep in mind that `"` is not the “right” way to type a double quote, and it's preferable to use the combinations ``` `` ```  and `''`.

If the quotes your text editor inserts are `“` and `”`, then the following should work:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`“
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1”{\text{#1}}
\mathcode`“="8000
```

But definitely *not* when using `pdflatex` and UTF-8 encoding. XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are OK. Again, I don't recommend such a type of markup, which is prone to errors and *less* readable than an explicit `\text{...}` markup.

Let's see how it works; the trick

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`“
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1”{\text{#1}}
```

is very common (it's in the TeXbook) in order to give a meaning to the active version of a character (in this case `“`) as `\lowercase` does its job and puts the converted token list back in the input stream, so that TeX will see the lowercase version of `~` (still active as is `~` in the default setting). Thus TeX will swallow

```
\def“#1”{\text{#1}}
```

The *macro* `“` is defined to look for the following `”` and consider anything in between as its argument, which is passed to `\text`.

With `` \mathcode`“="8000 `` we are telling (Xe)TeX that `“` in math mode must be converted to its active version. In text mode the nature of `“` is not changed.

Why does the first version, with `"`, work? Because `"` is *not* active, its category code is still 12 and the definition tells TeX to look for the next category 12 `"` that follow (it's converted to a mathcode only if it need to be, that is, if TeX is looking for mathcodes, which it doesn't when collecting the parameter text of a called macro).

Why doesn't the version with `“` work with `pdflatex`? Because this is not a seven bit character, so `pdftex` sees it as *two* characters (it's even wrong to say `` \lccode`~=`“ ``, in `pdftex`, as a stray character will remain). With XeTeX or LuaTeX, instead, multibyte characters are converted to a single entity before the engine starts the tokenization process.

Comment: OK, new undisclosed issue: my text editor uses the unicode quotes:  `“”` (which ensures the "right" quoting in the final output). I cannot seem to determine the "begin" and "endquote" in your TeX magic. Is it possible or is you method only suited for the same opening as closing character?

Comment: Shouldn't the second `"` in the `\def` not also be active? Could you explain the `\mathcode`"="8000` line a little?

Comment: @Martin: No, the second `"` doesn't have to be active; there is no such restriction on non-parameter tokens in parameter texts. A mathcode of 8000h means math-active: in math mode, the character is treated as if it were active, and TeX uses its meaning.

Comment: @Philipp Yes: mathcodes are not relevant when TeX parses the arguments to a macro. When the first `"` is found, its mathcode *is* relevant, so it is changed into its active counterpart, which is then expanded: its argument is delimited by a category 12 `"`.

Comment: @Philipp Normally the parameter text must have the correct catcode (see my answer). The reason this works here must be the `\mathcode` thing, which is kind of new to me.

Comment: @MartinScharrer It *has* the correct catcode; nowhere we say ``\catcode`"=13``, when the definition of the active dblquote is performed: you see that the final dblquote of the parameter text is *outside* the `\lowercase`.

Comment: egreg: I didn't meant that the catcode was wrong. I was talking about @Philipp's "there is no such restriction on non-parameter tokens in parameter texts", which isn't fully clear to me. What I meant is that the parameter text is catcode-sensitive, while it doesn't have to be the *active* catcode of course. I don't know much about `\mathcode` so far, that was the reason I asked the question.

Comment: @Martin: What I meant was "tokens in parameter texts don't have to be active". They have to match the catcode used at the caller site though.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by making `"` active (like e.g. `~` is) and define it as a macro which looks for another `"` as end-marker. You need to use the TeX `\def` primitive instead of LaTeX `\newcommand` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`\"=\active
\def"#1"{\text{#1}}

\begin{document}

"bla"

\text{bla}

$ a_{"bla"} = b_{\text{bla}} $

\end{document}
```

If you want to allow whole paragraphs add a `\long` before `\def`.

You have to be careful with packages which also redefine `"` like `babel` with some languages. You should have the above code after loading such packages.

Comment: How would this work in conjunction with Xe(La)TeX in which has special handling in non-math environments?

Comment: The above code uses TeX macros and will work with all TeX formats like pdflatex and xelatex. From which special handling are you talking exactly? If there is an specific issues, just edit your question to mentioned it. However, it should just work fine.

Comment: yes it does, I have edited the question to include my requirement of "math mode" only. People in the chat room said it was possible.