# Using \lccode / \lowercase{...} trick with double quote mark

Tags: macros, punctuation

My question was inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/using-simple-quotes-instead-of-text) in which it is described how to map `"#1"` in maths mode to `\text{#1}`:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`"
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1"{\text{#1}}
\mathcode`"="8000
```

As an exercise I decided to make a function `DefineMathText` such that `\DefineMathText{\~}` would turn all occurences of `~#1~` within maths mode into `\text{#1}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\DefineMathText#1{
    \begingroup
    \lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup%
      % do \def~#1~{\text{#1}}
      \def~##1~{\text{##1}}}
    % make #1 active in maths mode
    \mathcode`#1="8000
}
\begin{document}
\DefineMathText{\~}
This is a test: $a+b+c ~ test~$.
\end{document}
```

It works.

**But**, when I try to make the special character a double quote ", it fails:

```
\DefineMathText{"}
This is a test: $a+b+c " test"$.
% Runaway argument?
% test"$ \end {document}
% File ended while scanning use of ".
```

Attempt 2 suffers from the same error:

```
\DefineMathText{\"}
```

I think it may have something to do with `"` being matched to the right quote only. Yet if I do the definition directly (the first 3-liner) everything compiles and works.

**Is there some way I can get `\DefineMathText` to work with a double quote " ?**

Possibly related: I guess this is the same question as asking how to do `\DefineShortVerb{"}` in the `fancyvrb` package (say for some odd reason I wanted to map `"xxxx"` to `\verb!xxxx!`).

P.S. - this question is independent of how use(ful|less) the functionality is. `\text{...}` is not that hard to type and possibly clearer in the source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're defining the active `"` with a delimited argument; the delimiter you're asking for is an active `"`, which TeX will never find, because the `"` still has category code 12 when it's scanned in `$a+b+c " test"$`.

A correct definition would be

```
\def\DefineMathText#1{%
  \begingroup
  \lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~##1}#1{\text{##1}}%
  \mathcode`#1=\string"8000
}
```

and with this your second example will work. The first won't, however, because `~` *is* active. You can't do nothing about this, other than defining `~` to behave differently in text mode than in math mode. Note that the `` \mathcode`<char>="8000 `` works only when `<char>` has category code 11 or 12. The fact that your first example worked with `~`, is just because you *redefined* the active `~`, not because of the special math code.

Notice also that this trick *won't* work when some `babel` language module that activates `"` is loaded (for example `german`, `ngerman` or `italian`), unless some precautions are taken for reverting `"` to category code 12 in math mode.

The problem of mapping `"xxx"` to `\verb!xxx!` is different: here the delimiter *must* be active (and the same caution related to `babel` applies). But it's easier:

```
\catcode`"=\active
\def"{\verb"}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. The rabbit hole is deeper than I thought... thanks for that.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee There's always some Cheshire cat that can help you find the way.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: The handling of characters in math-mode using ``\mathcode`#1=\string"8000`` is a little confusing. I had issues understanding it as well. See my comments to egreg's answer to the above linked question.