# Increase the skip after a comma, in math mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, catcodes

I want to define a command `\widecomma`, so that `$\widecomma{a,b}$` looks the same as `$a,~b$`.  The following is my attempt.

```
\let\comma,
\newcommand{\widecomma}[1]{\begingroup\catcode`,=\active\newcommand,{\comma~}#1\endgroup}
```

But if I try it in the following MWE, `\inaccessible` error will be raised

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\comma,
\newcommand{\widecomma}[1]{\begingroup\catcode`,=\active\newcommand,{\comma~}#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
$\widecomma{a,b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I would use `expl3` and split a comma list with `,~` as separator.

Comment: @Gaussler Is it simple?  I drafted a (maybe similar) solution using `\foreach` from `tikz`, but it requires special treatment for the first or last entry.

Comment: Now I'm wondering a but, isn't this space a bit big then? Hear me out: here you have a comma with the extra spacing after it plus a word space. Wouldn't the equivalent of `a{,}~b` be more appropriate?

Comment: @daleif Which is what I do in my answer.

Comment: @egreg a bit convoluted?

Comment: @daleif Why? That's the normal way to locally make a character math active.

Comment: @egreg I just though Gausslers solution was much more simple and understandable.

Comment: @daleif Of course it is!

Comment: @egreg I would also prefer my solution for a totally different reason: If you do `\widecomma{a,H^{0,0}}`, you probably don’t want the changed spacing to affect the comma in the superscript (unless I’ve misunderstood something).

Comment: @Gaussler Yes, of course. Although it would be possible to cope with commas in subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: @Gaussler I added a workaround.

Comment: @egreg Great. However, there could be a million other cases that would also require a workaround. For instance, if one of the entries in the comma list is `f(x,y)`, perhaps you don’t want the spacing to apply to this comma. Whatever – it’s good to see different solutions that behave slightly differently. `;-)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than your attempt. Better to make the character math active rather than active *tout court*, so no category code is changed and `\widecomma` can also be used in the argument to another command.

The instruction `\let\comma=,` doesn't work, mainly because you want to save the *math code* of the comma.

```
\documentclass{article}

% save the math code of the comma
\mathchardef\normalcomma=\mathcode`,
% define a suitable meaning for the active comma
\newcommand{\activatewidecomma}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{{\normalcomma}\ }%
}
% in the scope of \widecomma the space after the comma will be wider
\newcommand{\widecomma}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % set up the wanted meaning and make the comma math active
  \activatewidecomma
  \mathcode`,="8000
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\widecomma{a,b}$ (wide)

$a,b$ (normal)

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as pointed out in comments, commas in subscripts or superscripts should not be affected by this behavior. We can fix the issue in the following way.

```
\documentclass{article}

% save the math code of the comma
\mathchardef\normalcomma=\mathcode`,
% define a suitable meaning for the active comma
\newcommand{\activatewidecomma}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\makewidecomma
}
% in the scope of \widecomma the space after the comma will be wider
\newcommand{\widecomma}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % set up the wanted meaning and make the comma math active
  \activatewidecomma
  \mathcode`,="8000
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\makewidecomma}{%
  {\normalcomma}% comma as an ordinary symbol
  \nonscript\mskip 6mu plus 3mu minus 2mu % space only in text or display style
}

\begin{document}

$\widecomma{a,b}$ (wide)

$a,b$ (normal)

$\widecomma{a,H^{0,0}}$ (wide)

$a,H^{0,0}$ (normal)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works so well.  The author has explained the trick [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50413/63179).

Comment: Wow...excellent suggestion...

Answer (score 6):

Following a request in the comments, I provide an `expl3` solution based on splitting a comma list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\widecomma}{ m }{
    \clist_use:nn { #1 } { {,}\  } % since ~ means space in expl3
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\( \widecomma{a, b, c} \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I guess one could use `\def`, `\cs_new:Npn`, or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` since `\clist_use:nn` is expandable. But I’m not sure if making `\widecomma` expandable could have unintended consequences. Probably not.

Comment: Probably `\clist_use:nn{#1}{{,}\ }` is better (notice the space after the backslash). No need for `\nobreakspace`, because TeX will never split a line after a comma or an ordinary symbol.

Comment: @egreg Updated. But I just tried replicating what the OP did with `~`.