# An environment which parses periods differently to redefine their behavior

Tags: markup

I have a collection of documents that I want to read into a LaTeX environment.  The problem is that these documents are not exactly formatted the way I would like.  I would like to create an environment which for the duration of the environment changes the way LaTeX parses `.` at the end of a sentence.  Essentially, I would like something which looks like:

```
\begin{mycontent}
   random content.  more random content.  some more random content.
\end{mycontent}
```

and parses it as though I had written

```
\begin{mycontent}
   random content.\formattingcommand  more random content.\formattingcommand  some more random content.\formattingcommand
\end{mycontent}
```

I don't have control over the content of the files getting passed to me, but I am guaranteed that the files are all structured the same.  I could write a Perl script to handle this, and normally I would.  But this is something that needs some kind of LaTeX wrapper that others can use without invoking Perl and works seamlessly for them.

It would be nice if I could write something like the following:

```
 \let\oldperiod{.}
 \def.{\oldperiod\formattingcommand}%
```

But `.` is not a command.  I've looked in the Knuth's `The TeXbook` in the section on sentences, but I don't see anything there I can immediately use.

I suppose I could do something that changes the cat code for `.` for the duration of the environment, but I need the old period to show up within this new environment.  I'm not really sure how to go this direction and would prefer not to.  But, I'm willing to be flexible on this point (particularly if someone's got something really *cool* to show.)

**Edit 1**

On the subject of catcodes:  I've never really worked with catcodes before. So I'm kind of blind going down that alley on my own right now.

**Edit 2**

If I follow *JosephWright*'s suggestion, I might worry that some other package I load might now have a clash in how an active period will be treated.  Is there a reason the following code has not been suggested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\formattingcommand}{DEMO}
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \def.{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
  }
  {}
\begin{document}
\begin{mycontent}
  random content.  more random content.  some more random content.
\end{mycontent}
\end{document}
```

I ask, because it would seem to me that this version should work, but when I try it I get an error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.11 \begin{mycontent}

?
```

**Edit 3**

Based upon everyone's feedback below, would the following be safe?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\formattingcommand}{DEMO}
\let\normalperiod=.%
\chardef\periodcatcode=\catcode`\.
\catcode`\.=\active
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \catcode`\.=\active%
    \def.{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
  }
  {}
\catcode`\.=\periodcatcode
\begin{document}
\begin{mycontent}
  random content.  more random content.  some more random content.
\end{mycontent}
\end{document}
```

By safe I mean:

1. `\let` saves the correct version of period (period with the expected catcode):  assuming I haven't done anything else wonky with catcodes earlier.
2. I've saved the current catcode before making it `\active`
3. I've made `.` have an `\active` cat code to ensure that solely within the scope of my environment it has the `\active` definition I'm giving it.  In other words, my definition is local in scope and won't effect definitions outside of its scope.
4. I've restored the catcode of `.` to what it was before creating my new environment without having to second-guess what that might have been.
5. If other packages wish to redefined an *active* `.`, my tinkering is invisible to them (assuming I'm not using any code related to those packaged within my environment).

Comment: As I (imperfectly) understand it, this is _exactly_ what catcodes are for.

Comment: But if I change the catcode, I still nevertheless need the period to show up.  How do I get the period there?

Comment: In exactly the way you suggest in your examples -- you save the old period using `let`. (I'm not sure the syntax is quite right, though.) You should read this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def

Comment: @Mohan In this case it shouldn't make any difference; although I too would use `\def\normalperiod{.}`; the syntax `\let\oldperiod{.}` is definitely wrong and it should be `\let\oldperiod=.` (the `=` is optional).

Comment: The code in "edit 3" is safe, but I wouldn't recommend it. I believe that the `\lowercase` method is to be preferred, if you don't want to assign a global meaning to the active period, but it's personal preference.

Comment: @egreg, so you're saying that "edit 3" could still inadvertently create a global meaning to an active period?  If so, then I must do much more research.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are on the right track with catcode changes. The key is to save the old definition of `.` with another name before applying the change. The standard approach would look something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \gdef.{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
\endgroup
\newcommand{\formattingcommand}{DEMO}
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
    \catcode`\.=\active
  }
  {}
\begin{document}
\begin{mycontent}
  random content.  more random content.  some more random content.
\end{mycontent}
\end{document}
```

where I've used a group to avoid needing to know what catcode `.` has more generally.

You might be surprised by the global definition of `.` here. The 'trick' is that the category code of `.` is only changed *locally*, and the definition only gets applied where where `.` is active.

As with anything relying on catcode changes, this will only work correctly if the 'content' has not already been read by TeX ('tokenized'). As such, don't use it if you content will have been used in the argument of some command. Also note that `babel` uses active characters a lot, and there is a risk of a clash if it is in use.

---

The reason that

```
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \def.{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
  }
  {}
```

fails is that when TeX reads the code, `.` is *not* active, and so `\def.` is incorrect (`\def` must be followed either by an active character or a macro name). Th `\newenvironment` command has read all of the 'start of environment' code but *not* executed it, so the fact it contains a `\catcode` line has no influence on the `\def` that follows.

You could avoid this in a couple of ways, for example

```
\catcode`\.=\active
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \def.{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
  }
\catcode`\.=12 % Assuming the usual set up: could be risky
```

or

```
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \lccode`\~=`.%
    \lowercase{%
      \def~{\normalperiod\formattingcommand}%
    }%
  }
```

which uses the fact that `~` is active in LaTeX documents, and that `\lowercase` preserves catcodes.

Of the two alternative approaches above, I would prefer the second (using `\lowercase`) over the one making `.` active for the entire definition of `mycontent`. If another package makes `.` active in some limited context, it would be possible for

```
\catcode`\.=\active
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {%
    \let\normalperiod=.%
```

to pick up a definition for an active `.` which was not actually correct (if in the general document `.` is *not* active).

Comment: Isn't `\gdef` redefining `.` globally?  I don't want `.` to change it's behavior outside of these environments.

Comment: @A.Ellett That defines globally the *active* period. When it has category code 12 that meaning is irrelevant.

Comment: @egreg. Wow!  I'm really in over my head.  The way I read this code, it looks like `.` has been made active for my entire document.  How it that this is not happening?

Comment: @A.Ellett the catcode assignment is local, only the definition of the active `.` is global.

Comment: @A.Ellett It is activated after `\begingroup`, so the category code assignment will end with `\endgroup`. But the definition of the active period is global, so it survives the group and it will be used whenever an active period is found (for instance in the `mycontent` environment).

Comment: @egreg.  I made some edits asking for further clarification.

Comment: Still over my head.  Why doesn't ``\catcode`\.=\active`` make `.` active by the time TeX reads the next line?

Comment: @A.Ellett The ``\catcode`\.=\active`` inside the `\newenvironment{mycontent}`  isn't executed until TeX sees `\begin{mycontent}`.  Its purpose is to make `.` active every time the environment is opened.

Comment: @mohan.  I'm getting a better picture.  Is there a way of writing `\let\oldcatcodeof.....?` to capture the current catcode of `.` and then after the definition of the environment write ``\catcode`\.=\oldcatecodeof``

Comment: @A.Ellett You don't need to restore the catcode of `.` as LaTeX environments are groups, so the change is 'trapped'. However, you can do ``\edef\temp{\the\catcode`\.}`` to define `\test` as a way to save the codecode. Usually this is done in the form ``\edef\temp{\catcode`\noexpand\.\the\catcode`\.}``.

Comment: @JosephWright Or ``\chardef\periodcatcode=\catcode`\.`` so one can say ``\catcode`\.=\periodcatcode`` to restore the original.

Comment: @egreg: is it better practice to do that or use groups? I would have thought groups, but your comment leaves me unsure...

Comment: @Mohan Groups are better, generally speaking.

Comment: I've made some edits to help talk about this better.  Am I understanding this?  In **Version II**, the catcode is changed so that `\def` can do its magic on `.`. But since the code isn't actually executed at that point, calling `\let\normalperiod.` isn't actually enacted until the environment is used.  So, am I right to assume that `\let` is not saving the value of an *active* `.` but rather the `.` with its *usual* catcode in the text where the environment is being called?

Comment: @A.Ellett That's correct, more or less. To be honest, of the three different code blocks, the second one is probably the riskiest (it will go wrong if there is some alternative definition for an active `.` about). The key to understanding all of this is tokenization, which is covered in other questions. (It's not realistic to cover all of the issues in one question: that soon makes things unwieldy.)

Comment: @egreg et al.  I think I've gotten a much better understanding of this.  I've tried to summarize my understand within my question (I've added a third edit).  I'll check out tokenization.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems to be aware of when dealing with category codes and active characters in particular.

1. When character tokens have already entered TeX, their category code is fixed (unless `\scantokens` is used, but this would open a can of worms).
2. If an active character somehow sneaks into a list for `\write`, there must be a definition for it.
3. `babel` makes some characters active, but delays doing so at `\begin{document}`

Assuming that making `.` active and defining its meaning to be "print a period and execute `\formatcommand`" solves your problem (and you haven't anything that could sneak in a `\write` such as a label containing a period), let's see a couple of alternatives.

#### Method 1

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef.{\normalperiod\formatcommand}
\endgroup
\newcommand\normalperiod{.}
\newcommand\formatcommand{whatever}
\newenvironment{mycontent}
 {\catcode`\.=\active}
 {}
```

This method is the easiest one. But it would break if `babel` is loaded with a language that makes the period active, or if some other package does the same.

#### Method 2

```
\newcommand\formatcommand{whatever}
\edef\normalperiod{\string.}
\newenvironment{mycontent}
  {\begingroup\lccode`~=`\.
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\normalperiod\formatcommand}%
   \catcode`\.=\active}
  {}
```

You still can't use the period inside `mycontents` for things that go into a `\write`, but this is a common limitation with every method.

This method is quite safe with `babel`, but of course it would override the meaning it may give to the active period. The `\edef` used for `\normalperiod` ensures that its replacement text is a normal category code 12 period, so if some other previously loaded package changes the category code, you're safe against it.

Comment: @JosephWright and egreg I find this `\lowercase` route interesting, but also perplexing.  It looks more like a hack to me.  Can someone point me to other answers on this site or references I can read to better appreciate this approach?

Comment: @A.Ellett I forgot the main assignment in method 2. :(

Comment: YEAH!  Works!  Perfect.  Now to read up on this solution and learn its magic.  :)

Comment: You can look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38012/4427) for an explanation of the `\lowercase` trick.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this comment.  My understanding of `\lowercase{\endgroud\def~}` is that `\lowercase` parses its argument and sends `\endgroup\def.` to the input stream.  This is somehow done while TeX sees an *active* token after `\def` to stop TeX from complaining about `.` being currently not *active*.  But the token `\endgroup` has not yet been acted upon essentially allowing us to smuggle in `.` to where it normal wouldn't be accepted and appropriately limiting the scope of `\lccode`.  Am I essentially correct?

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, you are.

Comment: Too bad I can't mark two answers as correct. :(  But between you and @JosephWright I now believe I understand how these suggestions work and accomplish what I need to get accomplished.