# Smallcaps for acroynms

Tags: packages, small-caps

Suppose I have lots of acronyms in my document , e.g. NASA. I want all my acronymns to be smallcaps by default. Is there a package that can recognise consecutive capital letters and make them smallcaps?

I know that I can write `\textsc{nasa}` or make a macro and write `\NASA`, but is there a package that can take away that complication by spotting say more than 2 consecutive capitals and setting smallcaps?

Answer (score 1):

It's realy difficult. A solution can consist to change all upper cased into active command see :

For this you sould look like to : [An environment which parses periods differently to redefine their behavior](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88678/an-environment-which-parses-periods-differently-to-redefine-their-behavior)  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode it's permit to set.

secondly you should check the second char to check if it's upper (see the xstring packge for it with the ifCase}. if it's upper, begin selecting textst and print the two char.

finaly set the space to be active and disable the previos biavior (you should define a global macro and undefine it on the space related command).

Comment: hmm, this is a start. are you saying that no solution exists?

Comment: A solution exists, but it's terribly messy. I would also consider the possibility where you *wouldn't* want the input automatically changed and how you could possibly stop it from doing so. Usually, 'automatic' is just an alternate spelling for 'annoying'.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
\newcommand\acronym[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}
```

you type *any* sequence of letters into smallcaps, whether you type `\acronym{NASA}`,  `\acronym{nasa}` or `\acronym{NasA}`.

Comment: Your idea it's not realy that people need, but it's can be usefull in some case. This man need an automatic detection of acronym

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.