# \scantokens not playing nice with \def or \gdef etc

Tags: input, catcodes, e-tex

I working in a context where I'm changing catcodes and need to rescan the tokens before proceeding to process the text.  But, I'm running into problems.  Even with this bare minimum code, I still have issues.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \scantokens{\gdef\ae@input{::#1::}}%%
  \endgroup
  \ae@input
  }%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\aeinput{HELLO}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\aeinput ...ae@input {::#1::}}\endgroup \ae@input
```

I get the same error if I write:

```
\scantokens{\xdef\ae@input{::#1::}}%%
```

Why is this not compiling?

Also, if I do something like

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\ae@input\expandafter{\scantokens{::#1::}}%%
```

I get the following error:

```
! File ended while scanning definition of \ae@input.
```

Even adding `\everyoef{\noexpand}` doesn't help.

**HOWEVER**, the following does work (which makes me even more confused).

```
\xdef\ae@input{\scantokens{::#1::}}%%
```

So, what's happening here?

**Where does this question come from?**

I thought I had a simple answer for [inputing text within an environment for which I've already changed the catcode of `.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452698/22413)  Basically, in that question I have an environment

```
\begin{speech}
   inside here periods have a different catcode

 \end{speech}
```

The OP for that question wanted to do something like

```
\begin{speech}
  \input{text.tex}
\end{speech}
```

Clearly, `\input` is not going to work here because `.` has the wrong catcode.  I thought I could easily remedy this (and allow the OP to continue writing `\input{text.tex}`) by doing something like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\.=\periodcatcode
  \scantokens{\gdef\ae@input{\input{#1}}}%%
  \endgroup
  \ae@input
  }%%
\makeatother
```

An alternative approach would have been to do something like

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\.=\periodcatcode
  \scantokens{\gdef\ae@filehandle{#1}}%%
  \endgroup
  \input{\ae@filehandle}%%
  }%%
\makeatother
```

That way, the input file would handle periods appropriately according to the `speech` environment.

Something like

```
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\.=\periodcatcode
  \scantokens{\input{#1}}%%
  \endgroup
}
```

Only superficially looks like it could work, but the input file would have not have the correct catcode for the periods anymore.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\xdef`?  This will also fully expand `#1`.  Why not just `\newcommand\aeinput[1]{\scantokens{#1\ignorespaces}}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke According to the `etex` documentation `\scantokens` *is* expandable.  But, let's say it's not.  Why in the world would `\xdef\ae@input{\scantokens{....}}` be the only instance for which my code compiled?

Comment: @HenriMenke You changed your comment before I noticed.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117906/use-of-everyeof-and-endlinechar-with-scantokens ?

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I have and I can't seem to make things work.  I've updated my answer to explain why your first suggestion is not tenable.

Comment: How about this http://termbin.com/4igx or even [`\input{\detokenize{text.txt}}`](http://termbin.com/aq77)?

Comment: @HenriMenke What I was trying to do would be to allow the OP avoid having to write out all of that code and just do something simple like `\aeinput{filehandle.tex}`  which would require me to rescan the tokens so I can get the correct catcode.

Comment: @HenriMenke But also, I'm just curious now why my own snippets aren't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `\scantokens` applies the category codes in force *when it's used*. Thus in

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \scantokens{\gdef\ae@input{::#1::}}%%
  \endgroup
  \ae@input
  }%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\aeinput{HELLO}
\end{document}
```

the `\scantokens` line is inserted in the doucment, where `@` is not a letter. So
`\gdef\ae@input` defines `\ae` as a macro to be followed by `@input` with replacement text `::<#1>::`. You need to change the category codes inside your group

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeinput[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \scantokens{\gdef\ae@input{::#1::}}%%
  \endgroup
  \ae@input
  }%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\aeinput{HELLO}
\end{document}
```

As you observe, whilst `\scantokens` is expandable, getting that right is a bit tricky as it has some oddities about the 'end of file' for the virtual file it uses. Those can be got around (see the `\tl_rescan:nn` code and similar in `expl3`), but it's non-trivial.

Comment: OMG.  How did I not see that!  Yikes.  Subtle, but also kind of obvious---at least for the amount of monkeying around I do with this stuff.  Thank you.