# Defining "#1" as \text{#1} in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to define `"#1"` as `\text{#1}` in math mode.

This worked:

```
\catcode`` = 13
\def``#1``{\text{#1}}
```

But if replace `` with ", it fails. I don't understand why. Is it possible to define `"` in this way ? And it possible to let this only work this way in math mode ?

Comment: Already answered here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/using-simple-quotes-instead-of-text

thanks @egreg

Answer (score 1):

Oh! You have a definition with a structure. Let us modify a bit your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\catcode`" = 13
\def"#1"{A{#1}}

"B"

\def"#1{C{#1}}

"B"D

\end{document}
```

The result is [image]

In fact `"` is defined as an active character. In the first definition additional `"` must appear after the parameter. In the similar way you made single quote active and then defined it in such a way that a parameter must be betwen a single quote and twice a single quote. Be aware: you are in  troubles.