# How can I change a glyph in a Verbatim environment?

Tags: symbols, verbatim, fancyvrb

I have a document which contains example program code in `Verbatim` environments. The caret symbol produced by typing `^` looks too flat to me, so I defined a macro to produce a sharper version.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

%A more wedge-like caret for use in code. 
\newcommand\pow{\hspace{-1pt}\raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{1.2}{\textsf{\textasciicircum}}}\hspace{-1pt}}

%Set up code environment  
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=12pt,xrightmargin=12pt,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
y = x^2  
y = x\pow2
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image: caret]

Unfortunately, it's easy to forget the necessity to use `\pow` and not `^` in code examples. Therefore I would like to set things up so that typing `^` in a `code` environment produces the result of `\pow`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: That definition of `\pow` doesn't seem “right”, it can have a different width than monospaced fonts. I would use a `\makebox` to the width of a single character in a monospaced font.

Comment: @Manuel --- Good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure you'll appreciate this devious trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

%A more wedge-like caret for use in code. 
\newcommand\pow{%
  \hspace{-1pt}%
  \raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{1.2}{\textsf{\textasciicircum}}}%
  \hspace{-1pt}%
}
\newcommand{\makehatpow}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`^
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\pow
  \catcode`^=\active
}

%Set up code environment  
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{
  xleftmargin=12pt,
  xrightmargin=12pt,
  commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={\makehatpow},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
y = x^2
y = x\pow2
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `codes` key should contain code that's executed before the usual verbatim category code assignments are performed. Luckily, `^` is not special inside a verbatim environment (like `>` or `` ` ``), so we can set it to be active, but before making it active, we (locally) define a meaning for the active `^` with the good old `` \begingroup\lccode`~=... `` trick. See [this answer or mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38012/4427) for more information.

Comment: I knew `catcodes` would come into it somewhere, but I don't understand the `\makehatpow` macro definition; can you add an explanation?